# Leader-Following Flocking/Steering in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a flocking algorithm in C# for my unity project.  I have tried to follow [this example](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-simple-rules-of-flocking-behaviors-alignment-cohesion-and-separation--gamedev-3444), but the problem is bringing everything together, and I'm failing to extrapolate.  The following code is part of my desire to have a leader-following flocking system.

I have added following/seeking steering to the basic three steering subroutines (alignment, cohesion, separation), but right now the boids just flock on top of the leader and shadow him.  I'd like for them to follow the leader, but also maintain separation from each other rather than just piling on each other like they're out of phase.

When the user selects a group of boids, and then selects where they should flock to, the boid closest is allocated leader and is assigned an A* path to the target.  The other boids then call the flocking instead of pathing code.

```
void Update()
{
    if (flock.Count > 0 && 
        flockLeader != gameObject)
    {
        Flocking();
    }
    else
    {
        Movement();
    }
}

private void Flocking()
{
    Vector3 vector = Vector3.zero, alignment = Alignment(), cohesion = Cohesion(), separation = Separation(), following = Following();
    int weightAlignment = 1, weightCohesion = 1, weightSeparation = 1, weightFollowing = 1;

    NeighbourhoodWatch(); // determine neighbour boids (exclude self)

    vector += (separation * weightSeparation);
    vector += (alignment * weightAlignment);
    vector += (cohesion * weightCohesion);
    vector += (following * weightFollowing);
    vector.Normalize();

    if (!vector.Equals(Vector3.zero))
    {
        if (Vector3.Angle(vector, transform.forward) >= 1f)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, vector, rateOfTurn * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f));
        }
        else // rotate and move
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, vector, rateOfTurn * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f));
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * (speed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
    }
}

private Vector3 Alignment()
{
    Vector3 vector = Vector3.zero;

    if (neighbourhood.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GameObject boid in neighbourhood)
        {
            vector += boid.transform.forward;
        }

        vector /= neighbourhood.Count;
    }

    return vector;
}

private Vector3 Cohesion()
{
    Vector3 vector = Vector3.zero;

    if (neighbourhood.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GameObject boid in neighbourhood)
        {
            vector += boid.transform.position; // acquire centre of mass
        }

        vector /= neighbourhood.Count;
        vector = vector - transform.position; // direction to centre of mass
    }

    return vector;
}

private Vector3 Separation()
{
    Vector3 vector = Vector3.zero;

    if (neighbourhood.Count > 0)
    {
        int spaceInvaders = 0;

        foreach (GameObject boid in neighbourhood)
        {
            float proximity = Vector3.Distance(boid.transform.position, transform.position);

            if (proximity <= footprint)
            {
                vector += boid.transform.position - transform.position;
                spaceInvaders++;
            }
        }

        if (spaceInvaders > 0)
        {
            vector /= spaceInvaders;
            vector *= -1; // negation (invert direction)
        }
    }

    return vector;
}

private Vector3 Following()
{
    Vector3 vector = Vector3.zero;

    vector = flockLeader.transform.position - transform.position;

    return vector;
}
```

Comment: Where are the swear words?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Pardon?

Comment: It was a play on your name :P

Comment: This code is just the calculation part which I hope is correct or otherwise I'm out! I think your problem is related to how you call these methods

Comment: I came across doing quite the same thing a few months ago : playing with weights is really important in order to achieve a proper effect. Also I found useful to add a bit of random : a 5th random vector with its weight, a random offset on speed and a random delay to change those random values regularly. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bijan are you saying the calculations look fine?  Flocking is called from the boid's update method.  Will edit question to clarify broader context.

Comment: @Kardux interesting, thank you, in this case does the way I have attempted to apply weighting make sense? (aside from it all being weighted 1 right now)

Comment: @inappropriateCode Yep I did quite the same thing : you can find the code I used [here](http://roy-bodereau.fr/Upload/BoidEntity.cs) (just noticed I set the cohesion weight to 0) and a video of how it looks using fish models [here](http://roy-bodereau.fr/Upload/boid_simulation_fishs_avoidance.mp4) (note that I used multiple boids "groups" to simulate various fish types.

Comment: @Kardux I think you've solved it!  Thank you!  I have started changing the weightings and it's behaving better, the boids are generally spacing out and being sensible.  Your code example was helpful! I changed weight to: alignment1 cohesion0.5 separation3 following2

Answer (score 0):

Well i have a few time trying something similar to this, if you want your units have a distance from your leader, just take the leader velocity and use that reverse vector, that reverse vector will be your units Destination, also use vector.scale if you want to ajust yourself the separation distance.